# Provided id of the wrong type for class got class java.lang.Integer

Tags: hibernate, rest, jersey

this is an error Every time when i call the getLocation method

> error - Provided id of the wrong type for class Expected: class  got class java.lang.Integer

```
@Id
@Column(name = "emi")
public String getEmi() {
    return emi;
}

public void setEmi(String emi) {
    this.emi = emi;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "latitude")
public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}
public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "longitude")
public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}
public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

this is how write themetjod in manager class

```
public Location getLocation(int id ) {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Location location = (Location) session.get(Location .class, id);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return location;
}
```

Comment: Is the error message complete?

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Provided id of the wrong type for class com.nsbm.entity.Location. Expected: class com.nsbm.entity.Location, got class java.lang.Integer

Comment: What is your primary key in Location table ?

Comment: @KushiHettiarachchi What is primary key in your Location table ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE tracker
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  emi character varying(50),
  latitude double precision,
  longitude double precision,
  CONSTRAINT tracker_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Comment: @Alpesh Jikadra this the table id is the primery key

Comment: @KushiHettiarachchi What do you mean by table id ? which data base you use ?

Comment: i am using postgress sq  data type  is integer   CREATE TABLE tracker
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  emi character varying(50),
  latitude double precision,
  longitude double precision,
  CONSTRAINT tracker_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Comment: @KushiHettiarachchi so eventually only one column (id) is your primary key, And you define all column as id in you Location class, that is the problem, there should be only one (id) column in Location which points to your primary key , https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity

Comment: thank you @Alpesh Jikadra now it is working perfect thank you very much for your suport

Comment: @KushiHettiarachchi you can accept the answer if it solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one primary key in your tracker table, and you have defined every column as an Id,

You Location class should be like below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tracker")
public class Location {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    public Integer getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "emi")
    public String getEmi() {
        return emi;
    }

    public void setEmi(String emi) {
        this.emi = emi;
    }

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

All other things look fine.

Try with this class.

Answer (score 0):

Type of the id given to the `session.get()` is wrong. You should've identified it by yourself already by the error message!

> Provided id of the wrong type for class com.nsbm.entity.Location. Expected: class com.nsbm.entity.Location, got class java.lang.Integer

You should change your `session.get()` method call in such a manner that you can resolve this issue. I don't know the logic on this method, but to resolve the problem I have pointed out the mistake for you.

```
public Location getLocation(int id ) {
    //some code here

    Location location = (Location) session.get(Location .class, id);
    // id that is being passed here in the sessin.get() method needs to be changed to type `com.nsbm.entity.Location` to resolve this error.

    //some code here
    return location;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i have alredy given the com.nsbm.entity.Location class 'id but it does not working